How to prove that a dynamic system (consist of the canonical Wiener process and Wiener shift ) is ergodic?
The definition follows from
Chueshov I. Monotone random systems theory and applications[M]. Springer, 2004.
and
Da Prato G, Zabczyk J. Ergodicity for infinite dimensional systems[M]. Cambridge university press, 1996.
A metric dynamic system $\theta=(\Omega,{\mathcal F}, P,\{\theta_t, t\in R\})$ is a probability space with a family of tranformations $\{\theta_t, t\in R\}$ such that:

$\{\theta_t, t\in R\}$ is a one-parameter group, i.e. $\theta_0=id$ and $\theta_t\circ\theta_s=\theta_{t+s},t,s \in R$;

$(t,\omega)\mapsto \theta_t\omega$ is $\mathcal B(R)\otimes {\mathcal F}/{\mathcal F}$ measurable;

$\forall t\in R,A\in{\mathcal F}, P(\theta_tA)=P(A)$ .


A set $A\in{\mathcal F}$ is called $\theta$-invariant if $P(\theta_tA\bigcap A)=P(A)$ for all $\forall t\in R,A\in{\mathcal F}$. $\theta$ is called ergodic under $P$ if for all $\theta$-invariant set $A \in \mathcal F$ we have $P(A)=0$ or $1$.
Let $W(t)=(W^1(t),\cdots,W^d(t))$ be a Wiener process in $R^d$ with two-side time $R$. Let $(\Omega,{\mathcal F}, P)$ be the corresponding canonical Wiener space. More precisely, let $C_0(R,R^d)$ be the space of all continuous functions $\omega$ from $R$ to $R^d$ such that $\omega(0)=0$ endowed with the topology generated by the metric
\begin{equation}
\rho(\omega,\omega^*)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\rho_n(\omega,\omega^*)}{1+\rho_n(\omega,\omega^*)},
\quad
\rho_n(\omega,\omega^*)=\max_{t\in [-n,n]}|\omega(t)-\omega^*(t)|.
\end{equation}
Let ${\mathcal F}$ be correspongding borel $\sigma$-algebra of $C_0(R,R^d)$ and $\theta_t$ (so-called wiener shift) be the corresponding measure preserving group:
$$
\theta_t\omega(\cdot)=\omega(t+\cdot)-\omega(t).
$$
Why such metric dynamic system is ergodic?
